# Python While loop with input with 2 functions

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 functions
func 1 (command) has while loop and input from user if user press 2 it's Excu Func 2
func 2 (handle) has while loop and input from user if user put any value Error it\s direct me again to the first func

Question Here : i don't want to go back to the first func i wann to stay in the same func (func 2) i don't want to go bake auto

what can i do ?

```
    def dash_command(self):
        x = True
        while self.__run and x:
            print(self.main_dash)
            try:
                cx = int(input("choose "))
                if cx == 1:
                    self.Show_clients()
                    # continue
                elif cx == 2:
                    cx__ = str(input("select  "))
                    self.cn = self.select_cli(cx__)
                    c = self.cn
                    if c is not None:
                        self.__Handle_conn(c)
                        x = False
                else:
                    return None
            except ValueError:
                print("Value Error")

    def __Handle_conn(self,conn):
        print(self.main_dash_2)
        x= True
        while conn and x:
            inp = int(input("Send Your Command"))
            if inp == 0:
                conn.close()
            elif inp == 1:
                try:
                    conn.send(str.encode("cwd"))
                    response = conn.recv(1024)
                    print(response)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
            elif inp == 2:
                xx = str(input("Send Command [cmd + command]"))
                try:
                    conn.send(str.encode(xx))
                    response = conn.recv(1024)
                    print(response)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    print("cmd + command")
                    # continue
            else:
                print("else loop")
                return
```

Comment: maybe you can try to call func2 when the user enters error values. Be sure that the func1 is ended properly and will not perform any more actions.

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)